# c++ overloading plus in an efficient way

Tags: c++, performance, operator-overloading

I wrote a class like this:

```
class vector3D{
    public:
    double x,y,z;
}
```

and i overload + operator:

```
class vector3D{
    public:
    double x,y,z;
    vector3D operator+(const vector3D &lhs)
    {
        vector3D temp(x+lhs.x,y+lhs.y,z+lhs.z);
        return temp;
    }
}
```

but using `C=A+B` is slower than

```
C.x = A.x + B.x;
C.y = A.y + B.y;
C.z = A.z + B.z;
```

i think it is because defining a vector3D instance in + overloading function. is there anyway to avoid this?

(FYI: i build with this flags: `-Wall -Wextra -Wunreachable-code -m32 -DNDEBUG -O2 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_REETRANT -D_THREAD_SAFE`)

EDIT:
this is how i test speed of two approach(in main() ):

```
//test bench
vector3D A(0.0,0.0,0.0), B(1e-9,1e-9,1e-9);
clock_t c = clock();
//case A
for(long int i=0;i<1000000000;i++)
{
    A = A + B;
}
cout<<"case A took: "<<1.0*(clock()-c)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC<<A<<endl;
c = clock();
//case B
for(long int i=0;i<1000000000;i++)
{
    A._x = A._x+B._x;
    A._y = A._x+B._y;
    A._z = A._x+B._z;
}
cout<<"case B took: "<<1.0*(clock()-c)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC<<A<<endl;
```

and the result is:

```
case A took: 5.539[1, 1, 1]
case B took: 1.531[2, 2, 2]
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Your `operator+` function is slower than those three lines that just add the components together, yes, but that function is doing a different thing from just those addition statements.

Comment: But i only want addition functionality! and i don't think repeating that three line over and over in my code would be wise... there must be a better way.

Comment: In your edited question, you're assigning to the member variables in `C`; what is `C`? Where do you declare and initialize it?

Comment: :) you are right. but what i meant was C=A+B; , .... i edited my question.

Comment: You may be interested in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473753/c11-return-value-optimization-or-move) on return value optimization.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're creating an additional object, it will carry some overhead. This is inherent.

However, looking at the "payload lines" you want, they are very similar to what you'd have in the body of `operator+=` adding some `other`:

```
vector3D &operator+=(const vector3D &other) // Note - no objects created.
{
    x += other.x;
    y += other.y;
    z += other.z;

    return *this; // Note - return by reference.
}
```

Of course, `operator+=` modifies its left operand (which is exactly why you have `operator+` with its object-creation overhead).

In general, you should prefer `operator+=` for heavy objects where it is applicable (see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28343969/operator-overloading-operator-vs-operator)).

Answer (score 0):

You may actually get a performance boost by collapsing this to one line and taking advantage of *return value optimization*:

```
vector3D operator+(const vector3D &lhs)
    {
        return vector3D(x+lhs.x,y+lhs.y,z+lhs.z);
    }
```

Comment: what is `temp` then? i should define it first! and that is slow

Comment: Sorry, bad cut and paste. Fixed now.